# Json.NET Schema IsValid returns true even if there is different type

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I have simple JSON object and JSON schema. JSON object property Name is String. And In Schema I am expecting integer. IsValid method returns true. I think it should return false, becouse there is type missmatch. I am missing something ?

```
//json
var hero = new Hero();
hero.Name = "Egid Beyond Meta";
hero.BattleRank = 5000;

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hero);
var deserialized = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output);

        // schema
        string schema = @"{
          'title' : 'Hero',
          'type' : 'object',
          'Name' : {'type' : 'integer'},
          'BattleRank' : {'type' : 'integer'},
          required: [ 'Name', 'BattleRank']
        }";

        var jsonSchema = JSchema.Parse(schema);

        // returns ture
        Console.WriteLine("is valid " + deserialized.IsValid(jsonSchema));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define your objects properties in the `properties` attribute of the schema like so:

```
string schema = @"{
    'title' : 'Hero',
    'type' : 'object',
    'properties': {
        'Name' : {'type' : 'integer'},
        'BattleRank' : {'type' : 'integer'},
    },
    required: [ 'Name', 'BattleRank']
}";
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nOrfos)

Answer (score 3):

Your schema is not correct it should be:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Name"      : { "type": ["string"]},
    "BattleRank": { "type": "integer"}
  },
  "required": ["Name","BattleRank"]
}
```

---

Generate your class's schema by using a schema generator (`Netonsoft.Json.Schema`) namespace / nuget package

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Hero));

schema.ToString();
```

Comment: Genuine question: why is there an array used for the type of `Name`?

Comment: It is not that it is an array, but it allows one to add to it with other items such as `"Name" : { "type" : ["string", null]}`. For our test purposes it could have been `"Name" : { "type" : "string"}`; my bad for leaving it on.